# I am getting error but it says the error is from module

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
   import time
    import multiprocessing
    def mydef(arg):
        time.sleep(arg)
        print("Seleeped for 1 Sec")
    pro=[]
    for _ in range(15):
        p=multiprocessing.Process(target=mydef,args=[1])
        p.start()
        pro.append(p)
    for proo in  pro:
        proo.join()
```

**error**

```
RuntimeError  File "C:\Users\admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\concurrent\futures\process.py", line 608, in _adjust_process_count
```

An attempt has been made to start a new process before the
current process has finished its bootstrapping phase.

This probably means that you are not using fork to start your
child processes and you have forgotten to use the proper idiom in the main module:

```
            if __name__ == '__main__':
                freeze_support()
                ...
```

The `freeze_support()` line can be omitted if the program is not going to be frozen to produce an executable.

```
    results = executor.map(do_something, secs)
```